# $C[0,1]$ is not Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Prove that the space $C[0,1]$ of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the inner product $ \langle f,g \rangle  =\int_{0}^{1} f(t)g(t)dt \quad $ is not Hilbert space.

I know that I have to find a Cauchy sequence  $(f_n)_n$ which converges to a function $f$ which is not continuous, but I can't construct such a sequence $(f_n)_n$.

Any help?

Comment: Please, oh please, write the inner product using `\langle f,g\rangle`, resulting in $\langle f,g\rangle$. `<` and `>` are for inequalities.

Comment: Try to find a sequence converging to a step function with just two values.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen That's one of my pet peeves. I've even had professors that wrote $(\cdot,\cdot)$ for the inner product. How hard is it to use the correct, unambiguous notation?

Answer (score 16):

Let $f_n:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$ be such that $$f_n(t)=\begin{cases}1, & \text{if $t\in[-1,0];$} \\1-nt, & \text{if $t\in[0,\tfrac1n]$;} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

According to Mathematica, we have $\lVert f_n-f_m\rVert=\frac{(m-n)^2}{3 m^2 n}$ if $1<n<m$ so this is indeed a Cauchy sequence.

```
In[1]:= f[n_] := Piecewise[{{1, t < 0}, {1 - n t, 0 <= t <= 1/n}}];

In[2]:= Integrate[(f[n]-f[m])^2, {t, -1, 1},  Assumptions-> 1<n<m] 

               2
        (m - n)
Out[2]= --------
            2
         3 m  n
```

Can you show it does not converge?

Comment: So I have to prove that $f_n(t)=\begin{cases}1-nt, & \text{if $t\in[0,\tfrac1n]$;} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$ does not converge. How can I do this?

Comment: For $ t > 1/n$ when $n \to \infty$ it is $f_n \to 0$ and for $t=0$ it is $f_n(0) \to 1$

Comment: (Notice I have changed the functions in my answer...) And why does *that* imply that the sequence I constructed does not converge with respect to the norm induced by your inner product?

Comment: The sequence you constructed is a sequence of continuous functions right?

Comment: Well... what do you think?

Comment: It is not uniform convergence right?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking, really: *what* is not uniform convergence?

Comment: I think I have blocked. Can you tell me if I wrote anything correct? Thank you!

Comment: Linking the related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241933/why-isnt-it-a-hilbert-space

Answer (score 7):

An alternative way (sledgehammer): if $C[0,1]$ where an Hilbert space then the linear continuous map $L\colon f\mapsto \int_0^{\frac 12}f(t)dt-\int_{\frac 12}^1f(t)dt$ would be represented by $g_0$.

Let $x\in (0,1/2)$ be fixed. Then consider a function $f_n$ such that $f_n(t)=1$ if $t\lt x$, $0\leqslant f_n\leqslant 1$ and $f_n(t)=0$ if $t\gt x+1/n$. We have $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}L(f_n)=x=\lim_{n\to +\infty}
\int_0^{x+1/n}g_0(t)f(t)\mathrm dt,$$
and the last limit is $\int_0^xg_0(t)\mathrm dt$. This proves that $g_0(t)=1$ for each $t\in (0,1/2)$. Similarly, we can prove that $g_0(t)=-1$ for each $t\in(1/2,1)$, hence $g_0$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: I think your $h_n$ should be defined differently, i.e. "$1$ on $[0,1/2 - 1/(2n)]$" or something similar. Could you elaborate how this implies that $g_0 = 1$ on [0,1/2)?

Comment: @el_tenedor You are right. I have edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to claim that in order to prove that the subspace $C[0,1]$ of $L^2[0,1]$ is not complete, it is sufficient to "find [in $C[0,1]$] a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)_n$ [i.e. Cauchy for the $L^2$-norm] which converges [in $L^2[0,1]$] to a function $f$ which is not continuous". It will even be useless to check that $(f_n)_n$ is $L^2$-Cauchy: this will result from the $L^2$-convergence.

The sequence of functions $f_n\in C[0,1]$ defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}n\left(x-\frac12\right)&\text{if }\left|x-\frac12\right|\le\frac1n\\+1&\text{if }x-\frac12\ge\frac1n\\-1&\text{if }x-\frac12\le-\frac1n\end{cases}$$
satisfies $|f_n|\le1$ and converges pointwise to the function $f$ defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=\frac12\\+1&\text{if }x>\frac12\\-1&\text{if }x<\frac12.\end{cases}$$
By the dominated convergence theorem, we deduce $\|f_n-f\|_2\to0.$

Because of its jump, the function $f$ is discontinuous, and more precisely: not *equal almost everywhere* to *any* continuous function.